# /etc/apt missing

Tags: 16.10

My `/etc/apt` directory was removed. I am using Ubuntu 16.10. How can I rebuild that directory?

Now `apt` command gives this error:

```
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ - DirectoryExists (2: No such file or directory)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ - DirectoryExists (2: No such file or directory)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/sources.list - RealFileExists (2: No such file or directory)
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27762/restore-etc-configuration-files-from-the-default

Comment: Restore from your backup, or reinstall Ubuntu.